# Convert parse text file into csv file using python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, xlrd

I have following sample data  from my text file. I am trying to convert that text file into csv file to clean the data.

The file text look like:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQZfy.png)

Text data:

```html
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        UniProt - Swiss-Prot Protein Knowledgebase
        SIB Swiss Institute of Bioinformatics; Geneva, Switzerland
        European Bioinformatics Institute (EBI); Hinxton, United Kingdom
        Protein Information Resource (PIR); Washington DC, USA
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Description: Human chromosome 1: entries, gene names and
             cross-references to MIM
Name:        humchr01.txt
Release:     2022_01 of 23-Feb-2022

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

This documents lists all the human protein sequence entries whose genes
are known to be encoded on chromosome 1 in this release of UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot.

Number of UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot entries encoded on chromosome 1: 2066

Reference for the chromosome sequence:
Nature 441:315-321(2006).
PubMed=16710414; DOI=10.1038/nature04727;

Gene           Chromosomal     Swiss-Prot             MIM    Description
name           position        AC        Entry name   code

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2           1p35.1          U3KPV4             gfjh     this best product
A3GALT2    [IGBS3S]          Q5VUY0      ADCL3_HUMAN  4231
 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
with open("demoata.txt", "r") as f:
    columns= f.read().splitlines()
    

with open("demoata.csv", "w") as out:
    out.write(",".join(columns))
```

The output would be:
[csv-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liC3Q.png)

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Are you _sure_ you can't find that same information in a machine-readable format?

Comment: In order to test this, we would at least need `demoata.txt` in text format (or a link to it) to allow it to be copy/pasted

Comment: By the way – the original data is not in the word-wrapped format of your screenshot. https://www.uniprot.org/docs/humchr01

Comment: Finally, the _third_ Google result for me for `humchr01.txt` is a tutorial explaining how to read exactly that particular file with Pandas. https://towardsdatascience.com/parsing-fixed-width-text-files-with-pandas-f1db8f737276

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can use Pandas fixed width format reader to help with this.

The following shows a slight variation to try and avoid specifying a large fixed `skiprows` parameter to skip over all of the lines at the start. It attempts to locate the actual start of the lines of data.

`skipfooter=4` is used as it probably more likely to remain fixed.

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from io import StringIO

req = requests.get("https://www.uniprot.org/docs/humchr01")
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
text = soup.pre.text
c = 0

for line_number, line in enumerate(StringIO(text), start=1):
    if line.startswith('___'):     # or '----'
        c += 1

        if c == 2:      # start of data
            skiprows = line_number
            break

names = ['Gene name', 'Chromosomal position', 'Swiss-Prot AC', 'Entry name', 'MIM code', 'Description']
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(text), names=names, skiprows=skiprows, index_col=False, header=None, skipfooter=4)
print(df)
```